# How to add the shipping TITLE to admin sales grid

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, shipping-methods

I want to add the shipping method **( shipping title NOT shipping description )** to the admin sales grid.

I've already added the shipping description using this code

```
$collection->getSelect()
       ->join('magento_sales_flat_order', 
              'main_table.entity_id = magento_sales_flat_order.entity_id',
               array('shipping_description'));
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

but this is not what i want, i want only the shipping title whithout the method name.